# Applications of Knapsack and Cutting Stock in Pure Math

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, reference-request, knapsack

I'm giving a seminar to PhD students in pure math, and one of the things I'd like to do is show that more applied optimization can also make its way into pure Mathematics. As for classical problems, I'll introduce knapsack and cutting stock (since I'll talk about column generation and DW decomposition).

They're working in Dynamical Systems, Algebraic Geometry, Symplectic Geometry, and Category Theory. Examples in these fields would be perfect, but of course, any examples will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: If knapsack and cutting-stock don't offer good applications, then other problems, that are easy to introduce (like min vertex cover), would also work.

Comment: Would you please, which one of applications you want to use for these examples?

Comment: Hey @A.Omidi, I'm used to seeing you on the PySCIPOPt github, nice seeing you here :) I don't want to use the problems for work, only to highlight that optimization can be useful for pure math. So I'm thinking of a knapsack application in Algebraic Geometry, for example, or a cutting stock application in Dynamical Systems, or any of the possibilities present in the post.

Comment: Dear @J. Dionisio, thanks. For Algebraic Geometry maybe some cutting plan approach being useful. Also, in Dynamical Systems some simulation techniques or sequential decision making might be helpful.